# How to fetch facebook 'updates' using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to write a Wordpress plugin that will fetch 'updates' of my friends or pages I like on facebook.

- Is that doable in PHP?

Any code sample? I tried to look [at Facebook for Websites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) but didn't find and example on how to get the updates.

- Any suggestions how this could be done?

Comment: Being that facebook is written in PHP, I would have to say yes, that is doable

Comment: I hope so :-) Just cannot find any sample/example how to retrieve friend's update....

Comment: I dont see is as relevant what facebook is written in? Surely its more to do with the API that Facebook exposes, or in the very worst case, the ability of the OP to scrape HTML

Comment: check out [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). I think this is what you want to use.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=facebook Source : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Let's start by the beginning. You can do this, sure. Facebook API is growing and you can do it for a very simple way, using "FQL".

Following the code (based on the facebook example):

```php
<?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '127375200698444',
    'secret' => '3584a791118c4d8811573c8184b51385',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $fql = 'SELECT status_id, message  from status where uid=' . $user;
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $updates = $facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'fql.query',
            'query' => $fql,
        ));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_status, friends_status',
  ));
}
```

The code above require an application registered at facebook (You can register on at https://developers.facebook.com/apps). Just register there and replace the appId and the secret with your values.

After all this done, you must echo the url $loginUrl to get the AuthToken of your user. With this token, you can get all the updates of him (using the fql of the example).

The Facebook type used in here is available at https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.

I hope this helps or at least have given a path.

Status FQL Docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/

API Method Docs (my example was based in here):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it would have to be a AJAX request from JavaScript on a set interval to check if a table has been updated, and if it has, refresh that results on the Page with AJAX. I would use jQuery for the AJAX syntax, it makes it much easier. And as for the PHP, just make it check to see if there are any changes in a table, if so, output the results in an `echo` and have jQuery append the results too the page. That seems like the most reasonable way to do it

#### EDIT

Check [jQuery.com](http://jquery.com) to learn jQuery ajax and interactions with PHP. Its pretty simple if you know any JavaScript or jQuery and PHP at all

Comment: I want to do it in php only. The code will fetch (new) updates and saves them in a database.

Comment: How do you plan on having them show up on the page though? Refresh the page? Thats a little clunky aha

Comment: I will just the text of the update. The text will be stored in a database. My question is how to get the text of friend's updates. PS I will save the text as Wordpress post.

Comment: Ah. Use the facebook API. Look it up, you will learn how to route facebook actions to your website